# Vue Apollo "__typename" is undefined in updateQuery

Tags: vue.js, graphql, strapi, vue-apollo

I'm attempting to create a "Show More" button for my posts index. The index query loads fine with the first 5 posts, when I click the Show More button I can see new posts being returned, however I receive a bunch of errors like:

```
Missing field id in {
  "__typename": "Post",
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": "5f2b26600c3ec47b279d8988",
      "title":
```

I receive one of each of these errors pretty much for each post attribute (id, title, content, slug, etc). This prevents the actual new posts from being added to the index. What causes this issue?

```
<script>

  import postsQuery from '~/apollo/queries/blog/posts';

  const pageSize = 5;

  export default {
    name: 'BlogIndex',

    data: () => ({
      loadingMorePosts: false,
      page: 0,
      pageSize,
    }),

    apollo: {
      postsCount: {
        prefetch: true,
        query: postsQuery,
        variables: {
          page: 0,
          pageSize,
        }
      },
      posts: {
        prefetch: true,
        query: postsQuery,
        variables: {
          page: 0,
          pageSize,
        }
      },
    },

    computed: {
      morePosts() {
        return this.posts.length < this.postsCount.aggregate.totalCount;
      }
    },

    methods: {
      async fetchMorePosts() {
        this.page += this.pageSize;

        this.$apollo.queries.posts.fetchMore({
          variables: {
            page: this.page,
            pageSize,
          },
          updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
            const newPosts = fetchMoreResult.posts;
            console.log('typename: ', previousResult.posts.__typename); <--- returns undefined

            if (!newPosts.length) return previousResult;

            return {
              posts: {
                __typename: previousResult.posts.__typename,
                posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...newPosts],
              }
            }
          }
        })
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE: added imported posts query

```
query Posts($page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!) {
  posts(
    start: $page
    limit: $pageSize
    sort: "published_at:desc"
    where: { published: true }
  ) {
    id
    title
    content
    slug
    published
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    published_at
  }
  postsCount: postsConnection(where: { published: true }) {
    aggregate {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the imported `postsQuery`

Comment: I knew I forgot something! Added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
            return {
              posts: {
                __typename: previousResult.posts.__typename,
                posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...newPosts],
              }
            }
```

I'm pretty sure `__typename` is supposed to belong to each post object, not part of the collection of posts. Let me know how if something like this fixes it:

```
            return {
              posts: {
                posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...newPosts]
              }
            }
```

and changing the query to:

```
query Posts($page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!) {
  posts(
    start: $page
    limit: $pageSize
    sort: "published_at:desc"
    where: { published: true }
  ) {
    __typename    // add this here
    id
    title
    content
    slug
    published
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    published_at
  }
  postsCount: postsConnection(where: { published: true }) {
    aggregate {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work, however writing the return like this does seem to work!

```return {posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...newPosts], postsCount: fetchMoreResult.postsCount}```

Comment: Why aren't you just returning? `[...previousResult.posts, ...newPosts]` (ive never worked with vue-apollo)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I know that when I just return the array of posts though, I get those missing field errors again though.